# Stipe, React Native, [Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Error"]

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing an app with Expo, Firebase Cloud Function and Stripe, for some reason the first time I navigate to the screen `CardPayment` the code returns the error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Error"]`, but if I refresh the screen the code runs perfectly. Anyone have any idea why and how I can fix it? I've tried a bunch of stuff, even using axios, but nothing seems to be working.

**Backend**

```
exports.addCardForExistingCustomer = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  
    const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
      {customer: `${req.query.customer}`},
      {apiVersion: '2020-08-27'}
    );
  
    const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({
      customer: `${req.query.customer}`
    });

    const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
      customer: `${req.query.customer}`,
      type: 'card',
    });
    
    res.json({
      setupIntent: setupIntent.client_secret,
      ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
      customer: `${req.query.customer}`,
      paymentMethods: paymentMethods,
    })
});
```

**Frontend**

```
    export default function CardPayment() {
    
      const { initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet } = useStripe();
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      const [customerId, setCustomerId] = useState('');
    
      const fetchPaymentSheetParams = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://<<path>>.cloudfunctions.net/addCardForExistingCustomer?customer=${customerId}`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
        const { setupIntent, ephemeralKey, customer } = await response.json();
    
        return {
          setupIntent,
          ephemeralKey,
          customer,
        };
      };
    
      const initializePaymentSheet = async () => {
        const {
          setupIntent,
          ephemeralKey,
          customer,
        } = await fetchPaymentSheetParams();
    
        console.log(setupIntent)
    
        const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
          customerId: customer,
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
          setupIntentClientSecret: setupIntent,
        });
        if (!error) {
          setLoading(true);
        } else {
          console.log(error)
        }
      };
    
    
      const openPaymentSheet = async () => {
    
        const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet();
    
        if (!error) {
          Alert.alert('Success', 'Your payment method is successfully set up for future payments!');
        }
      };
    
      const fetchCustomer = async () => {
       const fetchInformation = doc(db, 'clients', 'user', 'Information', auth.currentUser.uid)
       await getDoc(fetchInformation)
       .then((snapshot) => {
        const stripeId = snapshot.data().stripeCustomerId
        setCustomerId(stripeId)
        initializePaymentSheet();
      })
  }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchCustomer()
      }, []);
      
      if (loading == false) {
        return (
          <View>
            <ActivityIndicator/>
          </View>
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <View>
            <CustomButton
              buttonTxt={'Add Credit/Debit Card'}
              txtColor={'white'}
              backgroundColor={'black'}
              onPress={openPaymentSheet}
            />
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchCustomer` on the frontend isn't waiting for the `getDoc` promise chain to complete. Try putting `return` or `await` before the call to `getDoc`. If `return` is used, `fetchCustomer` as posted doesn't need to be an `async` function.

If this resolves the error, my guess would be that some kind of response caching is allowing the `then` handler of `getDoc(fetchInformation)` to win a race condition set up in promise job handling (in the microtask queue) when the page is reloaded.

The `getDoc` call handler (`async (snapshot) => {...}`) is missing an `await` operator before the `initializePaymentSheet();` call. Again this could set up an unpredictable race condition in the microtask queue if `initializePaymentSheet` is delayed.

Comment: I've tried what you said, I also updated the code above with your solution, but the error still persists

Comment: Thanks to your explanation, I figured another way to do it, and now it works perfectly ;)

Comment: Looking at the post again, `async (snapshot) => {...}` does need to be async but is missing an `await` operator before`initializePaymentSheet()`. There's a  pattern appearing here but glad you've got it working another way.